# API for PHP curl with JSON response using ajax to get cc result (using payeezy)?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, php-curl

I have a little problem now I'm using the PHP curl API with JSON request using ajax to submit the form (with the ajax part)? It doesn't submit the form or get a response. Does anyone have tips I can use to help me with the ajax part? I want everyone using payeezy to have the option to implement this code with your API. Also, am I using the user post PHP and data array parameters correctly?
[Here is the php form response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyXK1.png) note i rejected the card on purpose its the response i want.

[Here is the form itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eakdl.png)  i want ajax to submit the form here without refreshing the page and the json response to show up on the form page indicating if the transaction was successful or not. Also if the card is declined i do not want the form to submit and show its appropriate message.

```
<?php

#require_once('payeezy-include.php');

$apiKey = "(your api key)";

$apiSecret = "( your api secret)";

$token = "(your merchant token)";

$nonce = strval(hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(4, $cstrong))));

$timestamp = strval(time()*1000); //time stamp in milli seconds



$payload = getPayload();



/**

* Generate Payload

*/



   function getPayload($args = array())

{

$data = "";

$type = $_POST['type'];
$cardholder_name =  $_POST['cardholder_name'];
$card_number = $_POST['card_number'];
$exp_date = $_POST['exp_date'];
$cvv = $_POST['cvv'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$street = $_POST['street'];
$state_province = $_POST['state_province'];
$zip_postal_code = $_POST['zip_postal_code'];




    $data = array(

          'merchant_ref'=> '',

          'transaction_type'=> "purchase",

          'method'=> '$credit_card',

          'amount'=> '0001',

          'currency_code'=> 'USD',

          'credit_card'=> array(

                  'type'=> '$type',

                  'cardholder_name'=> '$cardholder_name',

                  'card_number'=> '$card_number',

                  'exp_date'=> '$exp_date',

                  'cvv'=> '$cvv',

                  'VerificationStr1'=> array(

                  'city'=> '$city',

                  'country'=> '$country',

                  'email'=> '$email',

                  'phone'=> array(

                  'number'=> '$number',

                  'street'=> '$street',

                  'state_province'=> '$state_province',

                  'zip_postal_code'=> '$zip_postal_code',

                )

           )

       )

);


return json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

}



$data = $apiKey . $nonce . $timestamp . $token . $payload;



$hashAlgorithm = "sha256";



### Make sure the HMAC hash is in hex -->

$hmac = hash_hmac ( $hashAlgorithm , $data , $apiSecret, false );



### Authorization : base64 of hmac hash -->

$hmac_enc = base64_encode($hmac);



$curl = curl_init('https://api.payeezy.com/v1/transactions');



$headers = array(

  'Content-Type: application/json',

  'apikey:'.strval($apiKey),

  'token:'.strval($token),

  'Authorization:'.$hmac_enc,

  'nonce:'.$nonce,

  'timestamp:'.$timestamp,

);



curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);



curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);



$json_response = curl_exec($curl);



$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);



$response = json_decode($json_response, true);



if ( $status != 201 ) {

    die("Error: call to URL $serviceURL failed with status $status, response        $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " .   curl_errno($curl));

}



curl_close($curl);

echo "JSON response is: ".$json_response."\n";

?>

//for the heck of it we will call it payment.php^ (the above code)

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/json; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1 ">
<title> </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<meta name="layout" content="main" />

<style>
.line-separator {
height: .2px;
background: #717171;
border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

.success{
border: 2px solid #00940;
background: #B3FFB3;
color: #555;
font-weight: bold;

}

.error {
border: 2px solid #DE001A;
background: #FFA8B3;
color: #000;
font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

<!--  JS and jquery reference Java-script files   -->

<script>
function letterspaceOnly(input) {
 var regex = /[^\n\r\t a-zA-Z0-9$.']/gi;
input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
}
</script>
<script>
function numbersOnly(input) {
var regex = /[^0-9]/gi;
input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
}
</script>
<script>
function emailOnly(input) {
   var regex = /[^0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%&'*+-/=?^_'{|}]/gi; 
   input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
 }
</script>

 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#pay").click(function() {
  var type = $("#type").val();
var cardholdername = $("#cardholder_name").val();
var cardnumber = $("#card_number").val();
var cvvcode = $("#cvv_code").val();
 var expdate = $("#exp_date").val();
  var city = $("#city").val();
var country = $("#country").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var number = $("#number").val();
var street = $("#street").val();
  var stateprovince = $("#state_province").val();
 var zippostalcode = $("#zip_postal_code").val();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:"ohyes.php"
  data:              "cardholder_name="+cardholdername+"&card_number="+cardnumber+"&cvv_code="+cvvcod    e+"&exp_date="+expdate+"&city="+city+"&country="+country+"&email="+email+"&numbe    r="+number+"&street="+street+"&state_province="+stateprovince+"&zip_postal_code=     "+zippostalcode,

  success: function(msg,string,jqXHR){
   $("#result").html(msg+string+jqXHR);
      }
    });
   });
  });

  </script>

</head>

<body>

    <br>

    <div>
        <a href="https://developer.payeezy.com" title="Home"> <img
            width="120" class="logo"
            src="https://developer.payeezy.com/sites/default/files/Payeezy-     DevelopersLogo_Horz.png"
            alt="Payeezy" />
        </a>
        <div align="right">
            <a href="index.html" title="Home">home page?</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div class="line-separator"></div>
    <div>

    </div>

    <form method="post" name="payment-info-form"  id="myForm">
        <h4 style="color: red">
            <span id="payment-errors"></span>
         </h4>
        <h4 style="color: green">
            <span id="response_msg"></span>
        </h4>
        <h4 style="color: blue">
            <span id="response_note"></span>
        </h4>
        <div id="someHiddenDiv" style="display: none; color: red">Requesting
            Payeezy token...</div>
        <table>

            <tr>
                <td align="right">Card Type :</td>
                <td><select required="" payeezy-data="type">
                        <option value="visa">Visa</option>
                        <option value="mastercard">Master Card</option>
                        <option value="American Express">American    Express</option>
                        <option value="discover">Discover</option>
 <option value="diners">Diners</option>
<option value="jcb">JCB</option>
                 </select></td>
             </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td align="right">Cardholder Name :</td>
                <td><input type="text" onkeyup="letterspaceOnly(this)"   required="" payeezy-data="cardholder_name"
                    value="" /></td>
             </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Card Number :</td>
                <td><input type="text" onkeyup="numbersOnly(this)"     required="" payeezy-data="card_number"
                    value="" minlength="16" maxlength="16" /></td>
             </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">CVV Code :</td>
                <td><input type="text" onkeyup="numbersOnly(this)"      minlength="3"  maxlength="4" payeezy-data="cvv_code" value="" />
<a href="https://www.cvvnumber.com/cvv.html" target="_blank" style="font- size:11px">What is my CVV code?</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Expiry Date :</td>
            <td><select required="" payeezy-data="exp_date">
                    <option value="01">01</option>
                    <option value="02">02</option>
                    <option value="03">03</option>
                    <option value="04">04</option>
                    <option value="05">05</option>
                    <option value="06">06</option>
                    <option value="07">07</option>
                    <option value="08">08</option>
                    <option value="09">09</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12" selected>12</option>
            </select> <select payeezy-data="exp_year">
                    <option value="17">2017</option>
                    <option value="18">2018</option>
                    <option value="19">2019</option>
                    <option value="20">2020</option>
                    <option value="21">2021</option>
                    <option value="16">2022</option>
                    <option value="17">2023</option>
                    <option value="18">2024</option>
                    <option value="19">2025</option>
                    <option value="20">2026</option>
                    <option value="21">2027</option>
                    <option value="16">2028</option>
                    <option value="17">2029</option>
                    <option value="18">2030</option>
                    <option value="19">2031</option>
                    <option value="20">2032</option>
                    <option value="21">2033</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">City :</td>
            <td><input type="text" onkeyup="letterspaceOnly(this)" required="" payeezy-data="city"
                value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Country :</td>
            <td><select required="" payeezy-data="country">
                    <option value="US">United States</option></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Email :</td>
            <td><input type="email" required="" onkeyup="emailOnly(this)" payeezy-data="email"
                value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Phone Number :</td>
            <td><input type="text" onkeyup="numbersOnly(this)" minlength="11" maxlength="11" required="" payeezy-data="number"
                value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Address :</td>
            <td><input type="text" onkeyup="letterspaceOnly(this)" required="" payeezy-data="street"
                value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">State Province :</td>
            <td><select  required="" payeezy-data="state_province"

<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
<option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
<option value="CA">California</option>
<option value="CO">Colorado</option>
<option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
<option value="DE">Delaware</option>
<option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
<option value="FL">Florida</option>
<option value="GA">Georgia</option>
<option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
<option value="ID">Idaho</option>
<option value="IL">Illinois</option>
<option value="IN">Indiana</option>
<option value="IA">Iowa</option>
<option value="KS">Kansas</option>
<option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
<option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
<option value="ME">Maine</option>
<option value="MD">Maryland</option>
<option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
<option value="MI">Michigan</option>
<option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
<option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
<option value="MO">Missouri</option>
<option value="MT">Montana</option>
<option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
<option value="NV">Nevada</option>
<option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
<option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
<option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
<option value="NY">New York</option>
<option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
<option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
<option value="OH">Ohio</option>
<option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
<option value="OR">Oregon</option>
<option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
<option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
<option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
<option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
<option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
<option value="TX">Texas</option>
<option value="UT">Utah</option>
<option value="VT">Vermont</option>
<option value="VA">Virginia</option>
<option value="WA">Washington</option>
<option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
<option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
<option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
<option value="GU">Guam</option>
<option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
<option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
<option value="UM">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
<option value="VI">Virgin Islands</option>
<option value="AA">Armed Forces Americas</option>
<option value="AP">Armed Forces Pacific</option>
<option value="AE">Armed Forces Others</option>
</select>                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Postal Code :</td>
            <td><input type="text" onkeyup="numbersOnly(this)" required="" payeezy-data="zip_postal_code" minlength="6" maxlength="9"
                value="" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="pay" value="submit"   onsumbmit="myForm()" class="btn"></td>
<p><div id="formResponse"></div></p>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

   </form>
  </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should provide a minimal example and explain in detail what is not working as expected.

Comment: Do you mean a screenshot?

Comment: I tried to explain it more specifically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lol i actually solved this along time ago... anyone using payeezy i want     them to use this so here is the ajax solution code below. I did this in alert     box so you can better understand it. Basically when the user clicks the button the form is passed to the processing page without leaving the page, in return     sending out a json response hence alert box. Now you can taylor that to your needs say an echo or something. The button starts the function. The Post is where the data arrays are sent to be processed. After the response is sent back in alert box.
```

Ps... I dont mind anyone using this template to go off of.

```
<html>
<head>
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">        </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.post("payment.php",
    {
      type: "$type",
      card_number: "$card_number",
      exp_date: "$exp_date",
      cvv: "$cvv",
      city: "$city",
      country: "$country",
      email: "$email",
      number: "$number",
      street: "$street",
      state_province: "$state_province",
      zip_postal_code: "$zip_postal_code"
    },
    function(data,status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back from     payment processor</button>
```